# How to store and access user data in database in Django?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, ocr, backend

I'm a newbie in Django and I'm building this web app that allows three different types of users to login. A customer, operator and an accountant. When the customer logs in, he is asked to upload two jpeg documents. When he is done, these documents will be converted into editable text(I'm using Google's Tesseract engine for Optical character recognition for this) and this data is stored in three columns. The first two columns are non editable but the third is editable. In the third column, the user makes changes if the converted text has any errors(since OCR is not 100 % accurate).

At this point an email has to be sent to the operator. The operator logs in and checks whether the customer has uploaded the the right documents or not. If there are any errors, he edits them and hits the save button. At this stage an email is sent to the accountant and he logs in to verify the data for the second time. If he confirms, an email is sent to the customer saying his documents have been verified.

As of now, my app is taking an image and converting it into editable text and displaying it in an HTML template. I need to know how to store this text in a table of three columns and make it available for the operator and accountant to edit. And also, I need to know how to make three different types of logins for three different users.

Please help. I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Some code that you've written would be helpful

Comment: Downvoted because: 
- you are asking two questions instead of just one.
- saving data to the database is trivial in django and extensively covered by the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/).
- you didn't include any code you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

You could've edited your question better but still, I'll try to answer as much as I understood:

Firstly let's start with the login. So, what you want is role-based login which you can easily achieve through Django auth_user and user_group. In this, you'll create a user through Django built-in auth system ([django authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/)) and after this assign a group to every user you create so that when you log in a user you can redirect him accordingly.

Next, you mentioned that you wanted to save data in DB. For that, you'll need to connect a DB through Django settings (my preference PostgreSQL) and then you have to create models according to your need ([django models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/)).

Lastly, for data read and write operations in DB you can look at Django ORM ([django ORM](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_orm/))

Comment: Thank you Bhawesh. I really appreciate your help. I will edit my question soon.

Comment: Ya sure, do comment here so I can help further. If this helped you do accept it.